# Change size of frame in tkinter, which is defined by a class

Tags: python, oop, tkinter, frame

I'm trying to change the size of my frames in [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter); I'm using python 3.0 and I'm creating an inventory management type thing for a school project. This is the code I have right now, and I'm trying to edit the dimensions of the frame. I have tried to look online but found nowhere the information I need. I'm aware that you need to use:

```
.geomtry()
```

built-in function, but I have no idea where to put it, or how to use it with a class.

```
                import tkinter as tk

            LARGE_FONT= ("Comic Sans MS", 12)
            SMALL_FONT=('Comic sans ms', 8)

            class StockManager(tk.Tk):

                def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
                    container = tk.Frame(self)

                    container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

                    container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
                    container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

                    self.frames = {}

                    for F in (StartPage, PageOne):
                        frame = F(container, self)

                        self.frames[F] = frame

                        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")


                    self.show_frame(StartPage)

                def show_frame(self, cont):
                    frame = self.frames[cont]
                    frame.tkraise()


            class StartPage(tk.Frame):

                def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

                    lbl1 = tk.Label(self, text='Welcome to the stock manager', font=LARGE_FONT)
                    lbl1.pack(pady=10, padx=10)
                    lbl2 = tk.Label(self, text='What would you like to do?', font=LARGE_FONT)
                    lbl2.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

                    btnShowProducts = tk.Button(self, text='1. Show all products ', font=LARGE_FONT,)
                    btnShowProducts.pack(anchor='w')

                    btnSearchProducts = tk.Button(self, text='2. Search for a product ', font=LARGE_FONT)
                    btnSearchProducts.pack(anchor='w')

                    btnAddProduct = tk.Button(self, text='3. Add another product ', font=LARGE_FONT)
                    btnAddProduct.pack(anchor='w')

                    btnDeleteProduct = tk.Button(self, text='4. Delete a product ', font=LARGE_FONT)

                    btnClose = tk.Button(self, text='Close Database ', font=LARGE_FONT)
                    btnClose.pack(anchor='w')

                    btnNextPage = tk.Button(self, text='Next Page', font=SMALL_FONT)
                    btnNextPage.pack(anchor='s')


            class PageOne(tk.Frame):

                def __init__(self, parent, controller):
                    tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
                    label = tk.Label(self, text="Page One!!!", font=LARGE_FONT)
                    label.pack(pady=10, padx=10)

                    btnAddTrans = tk.Button(self, text='1. Add a new transaction', font=('comic sans ms', 10))  ##CREATE ADD TRANSACTION HERE

                    btnShowTrans = tk.Button(self, text='2. Show Transactions', font=('Comic Sans MS', 10))
                    btnShowTrans.pack(anchor='w')

                    button1 = tk.Button(self, text="Back to Home")
                    button1.pack()

                    button2 = tk.Button(self, text="Next Page")
                    button2.pack()

            menu = StockManager()
            menu.mainloop()
```

Comment: Are you sure you mean Frame and _not_ Toplevel or Tk window?

Comment: im sorry , i thought that tk.Frame was the window its self, i mean when i run the program , a screen shows up with the following buttons and labels etc, and i want to increase the size of it without having to drag the corner, and by coding it, i hope that clears it up.

Comment: Please provide a workable example. Currently if I were to copy paste you code it would not run.

Comment: @Mike-SMT i will edit the question now with some code that you can run. apologies

Comment: @Mike-SMT edited brother

Comment: @bobdaves69 thanks for the edit but we do not need the full program. Just leave it at one button with what you have tried so far and where you are stuck. This is part of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). That being said I have provided an example of how you can change the window size with `geometry()` and `wininfo`.

Comment: "I'm using python 3.0"... surely, you should consider upgrading!

Comment: @ReblochonMasque i meant python 3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a simple example of how you can use the `geometry()` method to resize your window. This should help you understand a bit of how it work within a class.

```
import tkinter as tk


class My_App(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        # we need to set parent as a class attribute for later use
        self.parent = parent 
        button1 = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Make window larger!", command = self.make_window_bigger)
        button1.pack()

        button2 = tk.Button(self.parent, text="Make window Smaller!", command = self.make_window_smaller)
        button2.pack()

    def make_window_bigger(self):
        x = self.parent.winfo_height() + 10
        y = self.parent.winfo_width() + 10
        self.parent.geometry('{}x{}'.format(y, x))

    def make_window_smaller(self):
        x = self.parent.winfo_height() - 10
        y = self.parent.winfo_width() - 10
        self.parent.geometry('{}x{}'.format(y, x))

root = tk.Tk()
My_App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: so if i were to set the dimensions within the class, one way would be to simply do
    self.parent=parent
    self.parent.geometry(x,y)

Comment: not quite. You need to have it formatted as a string as geometry takes it as a string format. You will need to do it like this. `('{}x{}'.format(y, x)`. That being said the other part is correct. You just need to define the parent as the class attribute and use geometry like I showed.

Comment: @bobdaves69 no problem. Let me know how it goes when you test it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to resize a `Toplevel` or the `Tk` instance, you can use geometry method on the objects:

```
root.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(16, 32, 64, 128))
#self.geometry("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(16, 32, 64, 128))
#self.winfo_toplevel().geometry()("{}x{}+{}+{}".format(16, 32, 64, 128))
```

---

If you mean how to resize a `Frame`, you can simply set its `width` and `height` options:

```
frame = tk.Frame(root, bg='red', width=32, height=23)
#self.config(bg='red', width=32, height=23)
```

and if the frame is non-empty, you should additionally unset its propagation, in order to disallow resizing based on its children widgets' size demands, do so based on the geometry manager used by the children:

```
frame.pack_propagate(False) # discard either in accordance with the children
frame.grid_propagate(False)
#self.pack_propagate(False) # discard either in accordance with the children
#self.grid_propagate(False)
```

Comment: Your answer is a little unclear. If the frame is non-empty, setting propagation to False isn't optional if you want to specify the width and height on the frame itself. I think you know that, but your answer doesn't make that clear.

Comment: @BryanOakley Thanks for the help, I think it's clearer now. Initially, I thought it would resize to its given size if the widgets inside were to be destroyed but that seems wrong. One should unset the propagation exactly after the widget is in the size they wish.